# Installing a Windows 7 image using OEM key provided with new computer

Tags: windows, imaging

I work for a company of approximately 200 employees.  We order 2-3 computers a month and would like to create and deploy a standard Windows 7 Pro image to the new machines.  Is there a way to do this using the OEM license key that came installed originally on the machine? Is volume licensing my only option?

Thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the media that comes with these computer to make an image which would then accept the OEM key. At 200 computers, it might be worth your time to investigate Open Value licensing, it's a form of MS Volume licensing that's much more friendly to a business your size.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, too, that sysprep and various other deployment tools are specifically designed to NOT work with OEM media.  It's not fun to work on setting that all up, just to discover it's useless with the licenses you have... (wups!)

Another vote for volume licensing.